# How to write a ui:insert tag via Java

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, facelets

I would like to know how I can write a ui:insert facelet tag via ResponseWriter in Java. The problem is that I try with the following

```
ResponseWriter writer = context.getResponseWriter();

writer.startElement("ui:insert", null);
writer.writeAttribute("name", "http://www.blabla.com", null);
writer.endElement("ui:insert");
```

But it is not rendered correctly. I was looking for the component in books and Internet and I haven't found it yet.

Do you know how to do it?

Do you know what is the component related with that tag?

Comment: `ResponseWriter` writes HTML. `<ui:insert>` is not HTML.

Comment: So you say that there is no way to insert that tag via Java?

Comment: I didn't said that. Just that `ResponseWriter` is for HTML and that `<ui:insert>` is not HTML. You're just using the wrong tool for the job (you're simply doing the job at the wrong place and moment).